# How to classify an image from Azure Storage in Django using a Tensorflow model

Tags: django, tensorflow, django-models, azure-web-app-service

I am developing a django application where the user chooses a machine learning model from a drop down list and uploads an image for classification. This image was initially saved in the project directory (bad, I know) so that I can use it in the classification.

Now I save these images in Azure Storage, but at the moment I can't find a way to access them without having to save them locally to classify them, so I think I'll have to temporarily save them in the project directory and once I use them in the ml model, then I remove the images.

I would like to deploy this application to Azure web service, so I consider it is a bad idea to save and delete images in the project directory.

[You can see app's form here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3M2sA.png)

**models.py**
*image is saved in Azure Storage, the other fields in Azure Database for PostgreSQL.*

```
class UploadedImage(models.Model):
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='%Y/%m/%d/')
    uploaded = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=False, auto_now=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    prediction = models.FloatField(null=True, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

**forms.py**

```
class UploadImageForm(forms.ModelForm):
    EXTRA_CHOICES = [
       ('MOB', 'MobileNetV2'),
       ('VGG', 'VGG-19'),
       ('CNN', 'CNN 3BI'),
    ]
    predicted_with = forms.ChoiceField(label="Modelo Predictivo", 
                                        choices=EXTRA_CHOICES, required=True,
                                        widget=forms.Select(attrs={'class': 'form-control'})
                                      )
    class Meta:
        model = UploadedImage
        fields = [
            'image',
        ]
        widgets = {
            'image': forms.FileInput(attrs={'class':'custom-file-input'}),
        }
```

**views.py**

```
def make_prediction(image_to_predict, model='MOB'):
    tf.keras.backend.reset_uids()
    folders = {'VGG': 'vgg', 'MOB': 'mobilenet', 'CNN': 'cnn3', 'MSG': 'mobile_sin_gpu'}
    model_as_json = 'upload_images/model/%s/modelo.json' % (folders[model])
    weights = 'upload_images/model/%s/modelo.h5' % (folders[model])
    json_file = open(model_as_json, 'r')    
    loaded_json_model = json_file.read()
    json_file.close()
    model = tf.keras.models.model_from_json(loaded_json_model)
    model.load_weights(weights)
    image = [image_to_predict]
    data = img_preprocessing.create_data_batches(image)
    return model.predict(data)

def upload_image_view(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = forms.UploadImageForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            m = form.save(commit=False)
            try:
                pred = make_prediction(m.image.path, form.cleaned_data['predicted_with'])[0][0]
                if pred > 0.5:
                # Code continue...
            if status == 200:
                m.prediction = pred
                m.title = m.image.path
                m.save()
                # Code continue...
```

The above snippet worked when I initially saved the images in the project directory but when I started saving the images in Azure Storage I started getting this error:
`This backend doesn't support absolute paths.`

So I changed the following line: `pred = make_prediction(m.image.name, form.cleaned_data['predicted_with'])[0][0]`

However now I have this error: `NewRandomAccessFile failed to Create/Open: image-100.png : The system cannot find the file specified. ; No such file or directory [[{{node ReadFile}}]] [[IteratorGetNext]] [Op:__inference_predict_function_845] Function call stack: predict_function`

For this reason I think my solution would be to temporarily save the image in the project directory, use it in the model and then delete it, however, I do not think it is ideal.

What approach is appropriate to follow in this case?

Comment: [This article](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/images/classification) maybe useful to you.  You also can learn how to [cache data to disk in the data performance guide](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/data_performance#prefetching).

Comment: If your problem is solved, you are welcome to post your answer below the post, which can help more forum users.